Show Image in Plugin Development
I am developing a plugin. I am fetching information using API along with Image. My code is like below.
`$this->short_code .= '<div class="ft_wi_weather_all" >' . (  ( array_key_exists( 'weather_symbol', $meta_details ) && 'on' == $meta_details['weather_symbol'][0] ) ? '<div class="ft_wi_image"><img src="' . esc_url( 'http://openweathermap.org/img/w/' . $this->weather_info->weather[0]->icon . '.png' ) . '"></div>' : '' );`

I am checking my Plugin code using Plugin Check plugin. I am getting an error Images should be added using wp_get_attachment_image() or similar functions.
How to show image in WordPress Plugin Development which is fetched from API  ?
